# Update and Delete not working on Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I was trying to create a simple CRUD spring boot application after watching an online course. But the **update** and **delete** functions are not working. **GET** and **POST** is working, but **PUT** and **DELETE** is not working. I have inserted screenshots for the postman response at the end. I'm getting 200 OK response on postman but, why is it not working? Also, I'm using PostgreSQL for database.  Please help.

The session controller (**delete** and **update** are the last two methods) :

```
package com.organizer.conferencedemo.controllers;

import com.organizer.conferencedemo.models.Session;
import com.organizer.conferencedemo.repositories.SessionRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/sessions")
public class SessionsController {

    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Session> list() {
        return sessionRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    public Session get (@PathVariable Long id) {
        return sessionRepository.getOne(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Session create(@RequestBody final Session session) {
        return sessionRepository.saveAndFlush(session);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"id"}, method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id)
    {

        sessionRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"id"}, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public Session update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Session session)
    {
        Session existingSession = sessionRepository.getOne(id);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(session, existingSession, "session_id");
        return sessionRepository.saveAndFlush(existingSession);
    }
}
```

Session repository:

```
package com.organizer.conferencedemo.repositories;

import com.organizer.conferencedemo.models.Session;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface SessionRepository extends JpaRepository<Session, Long> {
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/conferencedb
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.organizer</groupId>
    <artifactId>conference-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>conference-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Build comments:

```
:: Spring Boot ::       (v2.1.10.RELEASE)

2020-01-26 16:36:58.221  INFO 10272 --- [           main] c.o.c.ConferenceDemoApplication          : Starting ConferenceDemoApplication on hp with PID 10272 (started by User in C:\Users\User\Documents\1. PERSONAL\8. IND PROJECTS\conference-demo\conference-demo)
2020-01-26 16:36:58.264  INFO 10272 --- [           main] c.o.c.ConferenceDemoApplication          : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-01-26 16:37:05.282  INFO 10272 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-01-26 16:37:05.979  INFO 10272 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 580ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.
2020-01-26 16:37:10.887  INFO 10272 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8550c927] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-01-26 16:37:14.000  INFO 10272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-01-26 16:37:14.550  INFO 10272 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-01-26 16:37:14.551  INFO 10272 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
2020-01-26 16:37:15.215  INFO 10272 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-01-26 16:37:15.216  INFO 10272 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 16441 ms
2020-01-26 16:37:28.898  INFO 10272 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-01-26 16:37:41.464  INFO 10272 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-01-26 16:37:44.305  INFO 10272 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2020-01-26 16:37:46.371  INFO 10272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.13.Final}
2020-01-26 16:37:46.382  INFO 10272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-01-26 16:37:48.374  INFO 10272 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2020-01-26 16:37:49.043  INFO 10272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2020-01-26 16:37:50.035  INFO 10272 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2020-01-26 16:37:50.070  INFO 10272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@571a01f9
2020-01-26 16:38:01.918  INFO 10272 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-01-26 16:38:09.233  INFO 10272 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-01-26 16:38:09.364  WARN 10272 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-01-26 16:38:10.388  INFO 10272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-01-26 16:38:10.394  INFO 10272 --- [           main] c.o.c.ConferenceDemoApplication          : Started ConferenceDemoApplication in 79.401 seconds (JVM running for 85.94)
2020-01-26 16:38:37.417  INFO 10272 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-01-26 16:38:37.417  INFO 10272 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-01-26 16:38:37.436  INFO 10272 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 19 ms
```

***create new session***:

[image: create new session]]

***update that session***:
After update the response should be with updated session name and description. But it's showing the old previous session name and description.

[image: update that session]]

***delete that session***:

For delete it shouldn't return anything. But it's returning details of that session id.

[image: delete that session]

Comment: your delete method returns void, and in your postman request for delete you are showing a returned body.

Comment: Updating and deleting is not. After update the response should be with updated session name and description. But it's showing the old previous session name and description. For delete it shouldn't return anything. But it's returning details of that session id. @Thomas Andolf

Comment: The code in your controller belongs in a service which should be `@Transactional`. You are modifying data without having a transaction.

Comment: So I should give ```@Transactional``` annotation for update and delete methods? @M. Deinum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enclose path variable parameters in the brackets in you mapping annotation in order this to work, otherwise `PUT` and `DELETE` requests wouldn't be matching and therefore ignored.

E.g:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Let me see if that works. :)

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thanks a lot for solving that. I was too blind to see that! :) @Bohdan Levchenko